# On the pseudo-Fibonacci and pseudo-Tribonacci sequences $A_n = \lceil e^{(n-1)/2}\rceil $ and $B_n = \lceil e^{\pi(n-1)/5}\rceil $

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function, fibonacci-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Define 
$$A_n = \lceil  e^{(n-1)/2}\rceil $$

with *ceiling function* $\lceil x\rceil$. Then starting with $n=0$ we get [A005181](http://oeis.org/A005181),

$$A_n = 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, \color{brown}{91, 149,\dots}$$

Compare to the *Fibonacci numbers*,

$$F_n = 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, \color{brown}{89, 144,\dots}$$

---

I was wondering if this had a tribonacci counterpart. After some quick experimentation, if we define
$$B_n = \lceil  e^{\pi(n-1)/5}\rceil $$

then,

$$B_n = 1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44, \color{brown}{82, 153,\dots}$$

Compare to the *tribonacci numbers*,

$$T_n = 1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44, \color{brown}{81, 149,\dots}$$

> **Questions:**

1. What is the tetranacci counterpart?
2. Is there a reason why such a family would exist other than mere coincidence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One should expect that there should be *some* approximations like this. It's not clear that there's an instructive analytic way to produce the *best* such approximation (one can in any case improve on $\frac{\pi}{5}$ for the Tribonacci sequence, see below), but probably there are ways to generate reasonably good choices that are canonical in some sense.

**Fibonacci** The Fibonacci sequence can be written using the given indexing as (this is *Binet's Formula*)
$$F_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \phi^{n + 1} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(-\frac{1}{\phi}\right)^{n + 1} ,$$
where $\phi := \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} = 1.61803\!\ldots$ is the **[Golden Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio)**. Now, the second term is small and decreases rapidly with $n$, so $F_n \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \phi^{n + 1}$, which can in turn be written in the form $e^{\alpha + \beta n}$, where $$\alpha = -\frac{1}{2} \log 5 + \log \phi = -0.32350\!\ldots, \qquad \beta = \log \phi = 0.48122\!\ldots .$$ Thus, by adjusting $\alpha$ and/or $\beta$, so that for small $n$ the total quantity is smaller than that the original exponential expression by at least the absolute value of the discarded term, at least for small $n$, we might expect to be able to produce $\alpha, \beta$ such that $$\lceil e^{\alpha + \beta n} \rceil = F_n \qquad \textrm{for small $n$}.$$ So, the fact that $F_n \approx \lceil e^{(n - 1) / 2} \rceil$ is partly a consequence of the approximation $\phi^2 \approx e$. N.b. the (linear) inequalities $$F_n - 1 < e^{\alpha + \beta n} \leq F_n, \qquad n = 0,\ldots,10,$$ cannot be satisfied simultaneously, so no choice of $\alpha, \beta$ yields more matching terms at the beginning of the sequence than the given choice $\alpha = -\frac{1}{2}, \beta = \frac{1}{2}$.

Something similar happens for the next few generalized Fibonnaci sequences.

**Tribonacci** The analogue of Binet's Formula is
$$T_n = \zeta r^n + \eta s^n + \bar\eta \bar s^n$$
for some constants $\zeta, \eta$ where $r = 1.83929\!\ldots, s, \bar s$ are the three roots of the characteristic polynomial $x^3 - x^2 - x - 1 = 0$ of the Tribonacci recursion $T_{n + 3} = T_{n + 2} + T_{n + 1} + T_n$. Now, $|\Re s| = \frac{1}{2} (r - 1) < 1$, so $T_n \approx \zeta r^n = \exp(\alpha + n \beta)$, where
$$\alpha = \log \zeta, \qquad \beta = \log r = 0.60937\!\ldots ,$$ and $\frac{\pi}{5} = 0.62831\!\ldots$ is certainly close to the latter. One can do a little better by taking $-\alpha = \beta$ to be $\frac{32}{51} = 0.62745\!\ldots$ or $\frac{4}{7} \log 3 = 0.62777\!\ldots$ (so that $e^{\beta} = 3^{4/7} = 1.87344\!\ldots$), both of which recover $T_8 = 81$, but one cannot reproduce any more terms.

**Tetranacci** The Tetranacci sequence is asymptotic to $\zeta r^n$ where $r = 1.92756\!\ldots$ is the largest real root of the characteristic polynomial $x^4 - x^3 - x^2 - x - 1$, so we expect $\beta \approx \log r = 0.65625\!\ldots$. This time the best we can do, at least when $\alpha = -\beta$, is reproducing all of the terms up through $108$, and taking $\beta = \frac{2}{3}$ will do so.